# Android: Localized standard Text for example OK, CANCEL and GPS not activated - for example?

Tags: android, android-layout, localization

I wish to localize my app and of course the text that is specific to my app i will need to localize but does some standard resources exist for standard Text like the OK and CANCEL

and GPS not activated etc?

Or do i have to localize absolutely everything?

Is there is some global text resources that ships with android how do i gain access to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`android.R.string`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html) contains the values used by the platform.

It would be better to define your own values as there have been inconsistencies reported with the `android.R.string` values. Read about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/MLWJ-prKGFo)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should add your own resources and translations, as the predefined resources can change between OS versions. I don't think that there common resources that you should use - the different stock applications have their own resources/translations.

There are for example some predefined android icons you can access using R.android but the recommendation is to make a local copy.