# What languages are Android resource strings translated in?

Tags: android, android-resources

If I am using a String such as `android.R.string.yes`, will all devices have this String in the device's selected language?  In other words, will this string be yes in Spanish on a Spanish phone, Chinese on a Chinese phone, etc? How you figured this out or links are appreciated!

I would attempt to check on my own but I have no language skills outside of English and don't want to get lost trying to navigate back to revert the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spanish on a Spanish phone, Chinese on a Chinese phone

Yes. All of the Android String resources are translated into many languages, and it will show in whatever language the phone is set to.

---

Check this:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/MLWJ-prKGFo/OR2m26uvYIUJ

> The only reason for using them (vs your own values) is to save
>   yourself the trouble of translating your own "yes/no" values should
>   you decide to support another language.

...And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576480/android-localized-standard-text-for-example-ok-cancel-and-gps-not-activated).